# May a tourist to be on a non-tourist mobile plan in Sri Lanka?

Tags: mobile-operators, sri-lanka

A [Dialog tourist plan](https://www.dialog.lk/tourist-plans) costs LKR 1300 where a [200 min plan](https://www.dialog.lk/mobile-prepaid-packages) costs LKR 132. Is it possible to get a new connection without hassle from Colombo without taking a tourist plan? Does it take a long time for the connection to be activated?

Comment: I have found the website TooManyAdapters.com useful. Their page on Sri Lanka connectivity is here: https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-sri-lanka/